# Save Attachments using Powershell

Tags: powershell, imap, mailkit

I am using Mailozaurr ([Mailozaurr Web Site](https://evotec.xyz/mailozaurr-new-mail-toolkit-smtp-imap-pop3-with-support-for-oauth-2-0-and-graphapi-for-powershell/)) to connect to my mailbox using IMAP and i am trying to download attachments

```
$Client = Connect-IMAP -Server 'outlook.office365.com' -Password $Password -UserName $UserName -Port 993 -Options Auto

Get-IMAPFolder -Client $Client
## Not yet sure how to best process messages
Get-IMAPMessage -Client $Client 
$messages = $client.Messages    
foreach($m in  $messages ){
foreach( $a in $m.Attachments){  
$a.WriteTo("MY-PATH\" + $a.FileName)
}
}
Disconnect-IMAP -Client $Client
```

But the file that i download is corrupted (can't use the file)

Comment: File is not corrupted.  It probably is compressed using GZIP or simply a base64 string.

Comment: @jdweng do you suggest any solution like convert String to Base64 or something like that ?

Comment: Use byte[] bytes =Convert.FromBase64String(string). If GZIP than decompress using : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=net-7.0&force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Powershell script worked for me

```
$dll = "YOUR PATH TO DLL IMAP"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dll)

$Username = "USERNAME"
$Password = "PASSWORD"


# Initialize the IMAP client
$client = New-Object ImapX.ImapClient

###set the fetching mode to retrieve the part of message you want to retrieve, 
###the less the better
$client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode = "Full"
$client.Host = "YOUR HOST"
$client.Port = PORT
$client.UseSsl = $true
$client.Connect()
$client.Login($Username, $Password)

# Get folder/label object containing emails you want to read from
$res = $client.folders| where { $_.path -eq 'Inbox' }


# Search email threads inside the subfolder
$numberOfMessagesLimit = 10
$messages = $res.search("ALL", $client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode, $numberOfMessagesLimit)

# Display the messages in a formatted table
$messages | ft *


foreach($m in $messages) {
$m.Subject
foreach($r in $m.Attachments) {
    $r.Download()
    $r.Save('PATH TO SAVE')
}
foreach($r in $m.EmbeddedResources){
$r.FileName
}
}
```